# Keep the file loaded in fileInput() when visiting another tab in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

In the `shiny` app below I have 2 different tabs and based on the tab selected I want a different `fileinput()` and a different `pickerInput()` to displayed while the other is hidden. Partially I did it but every time I change a tab the `fileInput()` is getting empty again when I return while it should keep its file.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(readxl)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Pricing model"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("fileInput"),
    uiOutput("var")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tabs",
      tabPanel("Amazon-HP"),
      tabPanel("Apple Desktop")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Define reactiveValues to store file data for each tab
  fileData <- reactiveValues(file1 = NULL, file2 = NULL)
  
  # Define a reactive function to read the uploaded file
  data1 <- reactive({
    req(fileData$file1)
    inFile <- fileData$file1
    readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath)
  })
  data2 <- reactive({
    req(fileData$file2)
    inFile <- fileData$file2
    readxl::read_excel(inFile$datapath)
  })
  
  
  # Observe the selected tab and dynamically render the appropriate fileInput
  observe({
    selected_tab <- input$tabs
    if (selected_tab == "Amazon-HP") {
      output$fileInput <- renderUI({
        fileInput("file1", "Choose an Excel file for Amazon-HP")
      })
    } else if (selected_tab == "Apple Desktop") {
      output$fileInput <- renderUI({
        fileInput("file2", "Choose an Excel file for Apple Desktop")
      })
    } 
  })
  
  # Observe the selected tab and dynamically render the appropriate varinput
  observe({
    selected_tab <- input$tabs
    if (selected_tab == "Amazon-HP") {
      output$var <- renderUI({
        req(fileData$file1)
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "s1",
          label = "Select variables",
          choices = colnames(data1())[-c(1, 2)],
          selected = colnames(data1())[-c(1, 2)],
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            `deselect-all-text` = "None",
            `select-all-text` = "All !",
            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
          )
        )
      })
    } else if (selected_tab == "Apple Desktop") {
      output$var <- renderUI({
        req(fileData$file2)
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "s2",
          label = "Select variables",
          choices = colnames(data2())[-c(1, 2)],
          selected = colnames(data2())[-c(1, 2)],
          multiple = TRUE,
          options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            `deselect-all-text` = "None",
            `select-all-text` = "All !",
            `none-selected-text` = "zero"
          )
        )
      })
    } e
  })
  
  # Observe changes in file input and update the reactiveValues
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    fileData$file1 <- input$file1
  })
  observeEvent(input$file2, {
    fileData$file2 <- input$file2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's happening because you are using `fileInput` as the id for both inputs. There's no need to use `renderUI` in this situation though as you can use `conditionalPanel` in the UI instead like this:

```
conditionalPanel(
  "input.tabs == 'Amazon-HP'",
  fileInput("file1", "Choose an Excel file for Amazon-HP")
),
conditionalPanel(
  "input.tabs == 'Apple Desktop'",
  fileInput("file2", "Choose an Excel file for Apple Desktop")
)
```

If you need `renderUI` in your actual use case, then just give them different ids in the server and replace the `fileInput` accordingly.

Comment: thank you could you provide that as a full answer?

Comment: i mean a full working exampe